# Why is the split() method approx. 2x slower when the result is pushed to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, split

Consider the following code snippet:

```js
function split() {
  let time = 0;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10 * 1000 * 1000; i++) {
    let start = performance.now();
    let words = "foo bar baz".split(" ");
    let end = performance.now();
    time += (end - start);
    // result.push(words);
  }
  console.log(`Time needed: ${time}ms`);
}
```

The output of this code is something like:

`Time needed: 2664ms`.

However, with the line `// result.push(words);` uncommented, the output is something like:

`Time needed: 4991ms`.

That's approx. 2x slower (note that I'm measuring only the time needed by `split()`, but not `push()`). Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Doing more is taking longer. What's weird in that?

Comment: `performance.now` doesn't have enough accuracy to give a good measurement of how long it took to run `let words = "foo bar baz".split(" ")`, so you're summing up a bunch of inaccurate numbers. I'd expect the output to vary from run to run, whether or not you uncomment that line. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now#reduced_time_precision

Comment: The times you get are more or less random. The loop is run fast, much faster then the resolution of `performance.now()`. Pull the timer-stuff out of the loop.

Comment: @NicholasTower I have run the code multiple times of course. I always made the same observation (and the numbers were pretty stable).

Comment: @RameshReddy Actually, if you look at the code closely, the "doing more" is outside of the time measurements. Doesn't change the fact that the measured duration is way too short to be accurately measured, though.

Comment: @derpirscher Ah, I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

performance.now() does not have the necessary accuracy to measure what you're trying to measure. The browser deliberately returns an inaccurate number from performance.now() in order to combat exploits like [spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)). So in both cases, the numbers you are seeing are not going to be accurate.

As for why you're getting *different* inaccurate numbers, here's my speculation. I'm guessing that most of the time, `end - start` is 0, because both timestamps are rounded to the same thing. So what you're really counting is the number of times where the rounding of the timestamp flips from one number to the next. Your first code might run through the loop 10 times, with 9 of them reporting 0ms, and 1 of them reporting 1ms. But then when you make the whole thing take longer, now it only takes 5 times through the loop for enough time to elapse that the rounding goes the other way. And so out of 10 times through the loop, 8 report 0ms and 2 report 1ms.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking your time 10.000.000 of times in a loop and get a overall sum of 2665 milliseconds. If "calculate" the length of one loop iteration, it is 0.0002665 milliseconds, ie about 0.27 microseconds. That's way below the accuracy of `performance.now`, which according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) is 5 microseconds (ie more than 20 times as big). Thus what you are measuring is more or less random ...

And just for demonstration purposes (yes, the measurement is still inaccurate): Doing both variants 1000 times and suming up the duration for each run will sum up to more or less the same, because the inaccuracies will cancel out each other. BTW I ran this test 4 times, and 3 times, split2() was "faster" ...

```js
function split1() {
  let time = 0;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10 * 1000; i++) {
    let start = performance.now();
    let words = "foo bar baz".split(" ");
    let end = performance.now();
    time += (end - start);
    //result.push(words);
  }
  return time;
}

function split2() {
  let time = 0;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10 * 1000; i++) {
    let start = performance.now();
    let words = "foo bar baz".split(" ");
    let end = performance.now();
    time += (end - start);
    result.push(words);
  }
  return time;
}


let total1 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
  total1 += split1();
  
let total2 = 0;
for (let i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
  total2 += split2();
  
console.log(total1.toFixed(1), total2.toFixed(1));
```